# Каким образом стоит поменять последний слой resnet18 чтобы улучшить accuracy?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, pytorch, компьютерное-зрение

Задача состоит в том, чтобы улучшить обычную часть архитектуры resnet18, заменив **последний линейный** слой модели на **несколько линейных** слоёв, причём имея между этими слоями слой **нелинейности**.

```
model = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
set_requires_grad(model, False)
num_ftrs = model.fc.in_features
model.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, num_classes) # в этом месте
```

Я пробовал делать следующим образом:

```
model.fc = nn.Sequential(nn.Flatten(), nn,Dropout(0.2), nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 128), nn.Relu(inplace=True), nn.Linear(128, num_classes))
```

Результат, разумеется, не поменялся.

Информация, которая может вам пригодится:

num_classes = 10

на последнем слое мы 512 классов приводим к 10

Comment: Почему вы решили, что точность вырастет? Линейный слой в конце работает с уже взвешенными фичмапами, просто "суммируя" результаты. Если хочется улучшить точность - попробуйте другую архитектуру(например, углубить саму сетку, скажем, до resnet50)

Answer (score 0):

А обучение на своих данных точно проводили?
Вкратце расскажу как можно сделать:

1. от стандартного resnet18 откусываем голову и получаем кодер фич (в интернете ищем что-то вроде timm Feature Extraction);
2. после тензора полученных фич ставим пару полносвязных слоев - получаем свою нейросеть;
3. обучаем полученную нейросеть на своем наборе картинок (на входе фичи, на выходе класс).